# Classic ASP - rewriting/redirecting an url changes ApplicationPool?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-8

I run a server with classic asp applications that previously had just one ApplicationPool for an specific client an it was accessed the following way:

**www.myentrepreisename.com/myclientname1**
**www.myentrepreisename.com/myclientname2**

As we got more customers the server load became higher and i am spliting the customers into different pools in order to improve the server use.

**myclientname1.myentreprisename.com (myclientname1pool)**
**myclientname2.myentreprisename.com (myclientname2pool)**

But, the customers doesn't know the new url and are still using the former way of access ( www.myentrepreisename.com/myclientname1 ).

Rewriting "www.myentrepreisename.com/myclientname1" to "myclientname1.myentreprisename.com" will change the applicationpool?

I read somewhere that the applicationpool selection occurs in http.sys so the  www.myentrepreisename.com/myclientname1 pool would always be selected and all customers woulb be still accessing the same pool. (Is that true?)

If instead of using rewrite i use redirect, would i be redirected to the correct ApplicationPool?

Comment: You can still perform a rewrite that will redirect that way it will use the App Pool associated with the Web Application instance.

Comment: "As we got more customers the server load became higher and i am spliting the customers into different pools in order to improve the server use." Please stop going the wrong way. You should set up load balancing cluster to handle high loads.